# initialize widget in Kendo grid cell?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Is there anyway to initialize a custom widget in a `kendo` grid cell (`td`)?

What I tried is

```
$("#container").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: dataSource,
        pageSize: 8,
    },
    height: 280,
    scrollable: {
        virtual: false
    },
    columns: ["Name", "StartTime", "EndTime"],
    rowTemplate: $.template($("#rowTemplate"))
});
```

in RowTemplate

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr><td>
        <div class="">
            {{html reFill(this.data) }}
        </div>
    </td></tr>                
</script>
```

```js
function reFill(data){
    var td = $('<div><div>').expander();
    return td[0].innerHTML;
}
```

The expander widget has a `div`, I am listing the click of the `div` to do some sort of things.

Here the problem is when I click that `div`, the click event is not triggering.

I want to know the problem is in the template or is there is any best way to initialize widget in kendo grid's cell?

Comment: where's your click function?